# URI.parse returning 0 for invalid URL

Tags: ruby

I have an invalid URL that I want to verify is invalid, however, Ruby's URI is saying that it's valid:

```
url = "https://blah.%20wordpress.com/"
# => "https://blah.%20wordpress.com/"
url =~ URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]
# => 0
```

Is there a way for me to confirm that it's invalid?

Comment: From my read of [RFC 3986 section 2.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), `%20` is valid because it's encoded. That it "looks" bad is a different problem. There are discussions that Ruby's URI isn't quite accurate and for a more rigid implemention of the spec you should use [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:UNSAFE]`

```
url = "https://blah.%20wordpress.com/"
url =~ URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:UNSAFE]
# => 13

safe_url = "https://blah.wordpress.com/"
safe_url =~ URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:UNSAFE]
# => nil
```